# Pull additional data besides grouped data

Tags: sql-server, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have a data set within Microsoft SQL that looks like so

```
ID       Value1     Value2
1         8           4
1         4           2
1         9           3 
1         3           1
2         4           9
2         5           7
2         6           4
2         7           5
2         1           1
```

I am trying to pull only the data from the corresponding row containing a max value in column 1 grouped by the ID number.  The result should be as follows

```
ID     Value1   Value2
1        9         3
2        7         5
```

The following is what I have tried, but have been unsuccessful.  It works if Value2 is removed.

```
USE [Database]
SELECT [ID],
       MAX([Value1]) as Value1,
       [Value2]
FROM [dbo].[Datatable]
GROUP BY [ID]
```

Comment: you could use a row_number() function (partition by ID order by value1 desc) then only select where the row number = 1

Comment: @ZLK I am pretty inexperienced with SQL, would you mind showing me what that would look like?

Comment: so something like `select id, value1, value2 from (select id, value1, value2, row_number() over (partition by id order by value1 desc) rn from datatable) t where rn = 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ROW_NUMBER()` window function can be used to partition the table by ID and rank the data within (by Value1 in descending order, in this case).

```
DECLARE @DataTable TABLE (ID INT, Value1 INT, Value2 INT);
INSERT @DataTable (ID, Value1, Value2)
VALUES (1, 8, 4)
     , (1, 4, 2)
     , (1, 9, 3)
     , (1, 3, 1)
     , (2, 4, 9)
     , (2, 5, 7)
     , (2, 6, 4)
     , (2, 7, 5)
     , (2, 1, 1);

SELECT ID, Value1, Value2
FROM (
    SELECT ID, Value1, Value2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Value1 DESC) RN
    FROM @DataTable) T
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Alternatively, if there are possible matches on the maximum value of Value1, use `RANK()` (or `DENSE_RANK()`)

Comment: I am confused as to what part of your solution pulls the max value of Value1 grouped by the ID?

Comment: @User247365 The WHERE clause at the end does it. RN is the column alias given to the ROW_NUMBER() function and you only want the first one for each ID. If you execute the select statement inside the subquery (`SELECT ID, Value1, Value2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Value1 DESC) RN FROM @DataTable`) you can see what it's doing. EDIT: to be clear, there's no need to use any sort of `GROUP BY` statement here.

Comment: @User247365 In case it's still confusing, window functions apply themselves after you have a result set. So the subquery is getting all the data, then applying a number to each of the rows based on how Value1 ranks within the IDs... Then the outer query only pulls the data from the rows with a rank of 1.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try searching for the Max value of value2 ? Like this

```
USE [Database]
SELECT [ID],
   MAX([Value1]) as Value1,
   MAX([Value2]) as Value2
FROM [dbo].[Datatable]
GROUP BY [ID]
```

Comment: I want the value corresponding with the same row as the max for value1, which is not necessarily the highest value for value2